# Java / TCP Traffic classes

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Well I notice in Java and presumably other languages there is a Socket option similar to

```
setTrafficClass(int tc)
```

I know the application I am using has a traffic class of 24, however despite googling I cannot find a list of what these classes correspond to, nor a list of valid ones.

Please enlighten me.
md_5

Answer (score 4):

According to the [specification for `Socket.setTrafficClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTrafficClass%28int%29), we see:

> For Internet Protocol v4 the value consists of an `integer`, the least significant 8 bits of which represent the value of the TOS octet in IP packets sent by the socket. RFC 1349 defines the TOS values as follows:
>
> - `IPTOS_LOWCOST` (`0x02`)
> - `IPTOS_RELIABILITY` (`0x04`)
> - `IPTOS_THROUGHPUT` (`0x08`)
> - `IPTOS_LOWDELAY` (`0x10`)
>
> The last low order bit is always ignored as this corresponds to the MBZ (must be zero) bit.

`24` is `0x18` i.e. `0x10 | 0x08`, which corresponds to `IPTOS_THROUGHPUT` and `IPTOS_LOWDELAY` being set.

As you can see, the TOS only serves as a *hint*; it requests high-throughput, low-delay routing... which may or may not be serviced!

You can read more on *types of service*  in [RFC 1349](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1349.txt) and the [relevant Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service).

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTrafficClass%28int%29) have some details. Essentially, you're setting the [TOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service) (type of service) header of your packet. The routing network may choose to use that as a suggestion on how to process the packet (or it might ignore it completely). A lot of networks don't actually do anything meaningful with this field, so I wouldn't rely on it's behaviour.

Comment: thanks, as you pointed out they document it in the UDP section.

Comment: @md_5 He didn't point that out, and his link points to the TCP section actually.

Answer (score 2):

Traffic class is ultimately a matter between you and your nearest router. The field has been through several mutations. It also varies between IPv4 and IPv6. The first definition for IPv4 was given in RFC 791-5; this was revised in [RFC 1349](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1349.txt), and redefined completely  in [RFC 2474](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2474.txt) as 'Differentiated Services'. The whole business may well have been revised again since I researched it for my book in 2003 or so. For IPv6 see RFC 2460. The stuff in the Javadoc about the `IPTOS_*` values refers to RFC 1349, and was already several years out of date when it was written.